# How do I get an MKMapView to zoom in on a few annotations?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, core-location, mkcoordinateregion

Given two or more CLLocation objects is there a method to return a MKCoordinateRegion zoomed in on the CLLocation objects (or maybe MKAnnotation objects)?

I'm thinking about writing a method that will iterate through annotations property of an MKMapView, find the max/min lat/lon of all annotations and set the center and span based on that (with some padding), but I don't want to go through the effort if it's already somewhere in the framework.

annotationsInMapRect does the inverse of what I want. Instead of a set of annotations located in the specified map rectangle, I want a method that will return a map rect that fits (with padding) a set of annotations.

Comment: In iOS 7, you can use the showAnnotations method and it will do everything for you.  For earlier iOS versions, there are plenty of answers in SO that show ways to calc the region.  I like the one that uses MKMapRectUnion.

Comment: That answers it! Thanks.